# How to make my service be stopped only by an admin?

Tags: c++, cmd, windows-services

I have a c++ application which runs as a windows service. I want to be sure that this service can only be closed by an admin. How is that done?
(A cmd command is what I'm looking for, though any other help would do great as well)
Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: no body except admin can stop service what's your mean need run cmd as administrator until stop service

Comment: You don't have to do a thing.  The default ACL for a new service only allows Administrators to send stop requests.  If your service is allowing non-admin users to stop it, you've done something wrong, and we'll need more details to figure out what.  (The code that installs the service would be the best bet.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that's what you're looking for, but maybe it helps:

**[Preventing users from stopping a particular service with a GPO.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2758d69a-60e8-4a5b-83dd-fc7d8e15bdc1/preventing-users-from-stopping-a-particular-service-with-a-gpo?forum=winserverGP)**

There are some little helpers that allow GPO-scripting, for example:

**[Five Command Line Tools for Managing Group Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg277500.aspx)**

That's maybe more than a short, single command, but it should do what you want: Restrict user access to the service configuration.

---

There might be another way to do that, it'll be much easier: You can create or update a service with the details of an admin account. There are various command line tools when it comes to service creation/configuration, but microsofts `sc.exe` and the usage of the `password`-option might be all you need:

> password=(string)
>
> A password string. This is required if an account other than LocalSystem is used.

**But...**

I wouldn't do it this way. First, i'm not sure if a service using an admin account is really restricted from other access. But it'll for sure change the permissions your service has. I don't know what your service does and if it's important what permissions it's running with, but it might be a problem.

If you change the service config, you change various things of that service at once.

If you use GPO policies, you just change the access to the service.

---

**That's the theory. In practice...**

...i have to admit that i myself haven't been able to create and run a service as desired. I tried to pack some python lines in a service structure and ended up diggin' through more problems than i had before. Even the service creation using username and password was somehow tricky and i tried various command line tools to do that *(sorry, i don't remember any names, though, and i deleted all data of this hopeless attempt)*.

As service creation doesn't seem to be your problem, see how this GPO scripting turns out for you.

Comment: If you needed to change or view the ACL for a service from the command line, you would do it with `sc sdset` and `sc sdshow`.  The service account password has nothing to do with it.  You can also change the ACL via group policy, as per your first link, but that's only sensible if you need to change a whole lot of machines at once.  For a single machine, you'd either use the command line or the services administrative tool.  (In this case, though, the OP is asking for something that happens by default anyway, so it really isn't clear what the problem is.)